# How to use perlbrew with zsh or bash?

Tags: bash, perl, zsh, perlbrew

Now I'm *really* confused about `perlbrew`...

In `perlbrew.pm` I see the following:

```
    if ($shell =~ /\/zsh\d?$/) {
        $shell_opt = "-d -f";
        # <snip>
    }
    elsif  ($shell =~ /\/bash$/)  {
       $shell_opt = "--noprofile --norc";
    }
```

AFAICT, those settings for `$shell_opt` mean that, at least if invoked from `zsh` or `bash`, `perlbrew use ...` will `exec`a new shell, *suppressing* the sourcing of all of the user's rc-type files.

I really have a hard time envisioning why *anyone* would want to work in a bare shell.  **What am I missing here?**  Is `perlbrew` meant for a use pattern different from standard interaction via a shell?  Or is it simply not intended for users of `zsh` or `bash`?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, in order for me to use one of the `perl`s installed by `perlbrew` I'd have to run something like

```
% perlbrew use perl-5.16.3
```

When one does so, the code shown above gets run, and as a result `perlbrew` `exec`'s a new shell, *with no rc-files*.  I don't see the point of working in an instance of my shell without my usual rc-files.

Comment: I use `perlbrew` in `bash`.  All I had to do was add a source line to my `.bashrc` file.  I don't follow your questions.  What is going wrong with your installation?

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR:** Your `env` is unusable by perlbrew, and needs to be fixed.

**Details:**
I had the same issue, where running `perlbrew switch ...` spawned a bare bash shell.  But I found this was because it was in the same session where I had installed perlbrew.  Though I had added it to .bash_profile, I had not sourced `~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` in my current shell.  (Side note: this was exasperated by using `screen`, and so my session persisted between disconnects.)

As far as I can tell, `perlbrew` distinguishes between two scenarios:

1. It already has the environment it needs; i.e., you have sourced `~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc`

- In this case, `perlbrew switch ...` automagically points `perl` to the version specified.  ***No subshell is spawned.***  This persists between logouts.

3. You have a bare shell, or an environment otherwise unusable by `perlbrew` (e.g., ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` has not been sourced).

- Since it cannot run in the current environment, `perlbrew` throws its hands up, and ***spawns a new subshell***.  This is when it executes the `--norc` code you found, and uses a bare shell into which it populates its own environment variables.
- Note that this scenario may also occur in scripts.  See [Perlbrew in Shell Scripts](http://perlbrew.pl/Perlbrew-In-Shell-Scripts.html) for more information.

Why would the project want to spawn a bare shell in Senario #2?  Yeah, that's a good question, but the more I've thought about it, I'm sure they had their reasons.  My current take on this is that `perlbrew` is looking out for itself at this point.  Your environment, presumably configured by your rc, was unusable.  In a pathological case, perhaps it unset all of the environment variables it needs.  Regardless, the subshell logic is a pretty bullet-proof way to make sure `perlbrew` will run as it needs.

One last note - if putting `source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc` into `.bash_profile`  meant creating a *new file*, then your .bashrc may need to be *explicitly* sourced from that file, as `.profile` may no longer do it:

> ```
> $ head -3 .profile
> ```

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
```

Answer (score 2):

No idea why it's like that, but that code is not normally executed. You have to explicitly execute the `perlbrew` binary to reach that code from bash. But the `use` and `switch` features (which call the sub containing the quoted code) are normally handled by the `perlbrew` shell function.

Comment: I remain as puzzled as ever.  AFAICT, if I want to use the `perl` I installed with `perlbrew`, I need to run something like `perlbrew use perl-5.16.3`, and this ***definitely*** runs the code I pointed out (I confirmed this).  IOW, I can't see how I could use `perlbrew` without running this code.

Comment: Something's wrong with your install if it runs the code you pointed. You're suppose to source a script in your `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

Don't mind me: I didn't realise that the spawned shell was used interactively.

---

A program running in a shell that has sourced its rc-files is stuck with whatever those rc-files do. In a pathological case, a .bashrc might alias `echo` to `rm -rf`, causing the random deletion of some unfortunately-named files and directories (and filling the console or logfile with garbage errors). `perlbrew.pm` needs to run some commands through a shell, and is taking care to ensure that it doesn't accidentally nuke anything because some rc-file had something weird in it.

No human user would want to work without their rc-files. Humans, however, can compensate for how their personal setup differs from the norm. `perlbrew` cannot.

Comment: Makes sense if the shell was used by perlbrew, but it's actually used interactively by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to source the perlbrew rc file in your script to set up the paths without launching a sub-shell.

From: https://github.com/gugod/App-perlbrew/wiki/Perlbrew-In-Shell-Scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash
## These 3 lines are mandatory.
export PERLBREW_ROOT=/opt/perlbrew
export PERLBREW_HOME=/tmp/.perlbrew
source ${PERLBREW_ROOT}/etc/bashrc

## Do stuff with 5.14.1
perlbrew use 5.14.1
perl /app/my-modern-program
```